# Find a Specific String in Excel File using Apache POI API

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm new to Apache POI API for reading MS Office Documents but somehow good at Java. I just want to search a specific String from an Excel File! I'm doing in this way:

```
   private void processExcelFile(File f_path) throws Exception{
    File path=f_path;
    
    try{
            
        FileInputStream is=new FileInputStream(path);
        
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(is);
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        
        int rowcount_post=0;
        int rowcount_304=0;
        
                for(Row row: sheet){
                    for(Cell cell : row){
                        
                        if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING){
                                if (cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString().trim().equals("GET")){
                                        rowcount_post=row.getRowNum();
                                     
                                        HSSFRow removingRow = sheet.getRow(rowcount_post);
                                            
                                            if (removingRow != null) {
                                            sheet.removeRow(removingRow);
                                            }
                                            
                                     try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:/juni.xls")) {
                                        wb.write(fileOut);
                                    }
                                    break;
                                }
                                else{
                                    System.out.print("NOT FOUND");
                                    
                                }
                                
                              
                        break;
                        }
                          
                    }
                }
               
    }
    catch(Exception e){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,e.getMessage(),"Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

All is working fine! Except that I have a Web Generated Log file. So I have to search it for some Strings and then I have to delete the line containing that string.

The problem is that it only works for the Excel Files I'm creating by my hand but not for computer generated (AUTOMATIC LOG FILE) file. Suppose that I have to search a string "POST" it will only find in the file generated by me but not in the file generated by the website. Is it any Encoding problem I mean the text encoded or whatever!

Please suggest me a solution for this.

Comment: I feel that the website generated excel file does not have defined cells. All the data is in 1 cell of the excel file.

Comment: so what can i do for the solution? please can you help me?

Comment: Instead of (cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString().trim().equals("GET") use (cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString().trim().contains("GET")

Comment: i have tried it my dear ;(

Comment: also can you please give me any idea i want to delete all the rows that will contain the specific string i want to delete please?

Comment: When you read the generated Excel file, use log/sysout/debug to see the value of each cell.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more how please

Answer (score 0):

There are two bugs I noticed in your code. First, you write the file every time you remove a row which is inefficient. Second, you only search the FIRST string-cell in the row, and if the first string-cell in the row isn't the correct one, you break.  If your automatically generated file saves numbers or blank cells as strings (possible), then this will cause a difference between your hand generated excel file and the one you created with the script. I would suggest removing the second break statement. To clean up the code, I would rewrite the whole if block as follows:

```
if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING && cell.getStringCellValue().equals("GET")){
    sheet.removeRow(row);
    break;
} else {
    System.out.print("Not Found! ");
}
```

The if statement works because of short circuiting. This will save you a whole lot of time if you are new to apache poi. :)

After we have removed the rows, we should then write the file.
Place the following after the whole for block:

```
try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:/juni.xls")) {
    wb.write(fileOut);
}
```

I'm assuming that sheet.removeRow(row) will work in an enhanced for loop. If it doesn't, you may need to fix it or make your code work in a while loop. Hint:  while((row = sheet.getRow(i)) != null ){  }

Comment: @user2496503 What was wrong with it? what errors were thrown? also, can you show an example of the automatic xls file that was returned.